# Nice olympiad inequality $\frac{1}{(a+b+c)}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{7a+b})\leq \frac{1}{8}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math, alternative-proof, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have the following problem :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a\geq b \geq c $ then we have :
> $$\frac{1}{(a+b+c)}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{7a+b})\leq \frac{1}{8}$$

My proof :

We begin with two lemma :

> First lemma :
> Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a\geq b \geq c $ then we have :$$(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{7a+b})\leq \frac{3}{8}$$

I didn’t prove it because it's easy .So the second lemma .

> Second lemma :
> Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a\geq b \geq c $ then we have :
> $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{7a+b}\geq \sum_{cyc}\frac{ac}{7a+b}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{7a+b}$$

It's an easy consequence of the rearrangement inequality .

Now the proof :

We have with the original condition and the first lemma :

$$\frac{(a+b+c)}{(a+b+c)}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{7a+b})\leq \frac{3}{8}$$

Or :

$$\frac{1}{(a+b+c)}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{7a+b}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{ac}{7a+b}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{7a+b})\leq \frac{3}{8}$$

With the second lemma we have :
$$\frac{3}{(a+b+c)}(\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{7a+b})\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{7a+b}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{ac}{7a+b}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{7a+b}\leq \frac{3}{8}$$

Done !

My question is: Do you have an alternative proof ?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: In your first lemma, if you put a=b=c, then the value of the summation is 3/8 which is greater than 1/8. How did you prove your lemma 1

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the relation between $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$ and $a+b+c$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{7a+b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{7}{b}+\frac{1}{a}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{49}{7b}+\frac{1}{a}}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{64}{7b+a}}=\frac{a+b+c}{8}.$$

Comment: What is c-s here?

Comment: @Rishabh Jain Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.